# Can we have control over CPU usage when using Parallel.Foreach in C#?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, cpu-usage, parallel.foreach

I want to process thousands of records using `Parallel.Foreach`, but the CPU usage is 100%.

```
Parallel.ForEach(PhotoPaths, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, photopath =>
{
    RemovePhoto(photo);
});

public void RemovePhoto(string photopath)
{
    File.Delete(photopath); 
}
```

If I use `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2`, my operation is getting timed out.

With a normal foreach loop it is getting timed out so I have choose `Parallel.Foreach` with which my task is completing but the only problem is CPU utilisation is 100%. Please let me know if we have any alternatives.

Comment: This is in the comment because it would not answer your question, but why? Usually just let the OS decides what to do with the CPU.

Comment: `but the cpu usage is 100 %` - that is the point of parallel processing, to utilize all cores at the same time.

Comment: If the CPU usage is 100% then you are using all available CPU cycles... what more are you expecting?

Comment: Take a step back, tell us what it is you are actually doing *inside* the loop. Better yet share the relevant code in the loop.

Comment: If you think the 100% is a problem, then please see [ZOMG! This program is using 100% CPU!1! Think of the puppies!!11!!1!1!eleven](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101203-00/?p=12123). If you want to limit how fast you are processing records, then it's a Possible duplicate of [throttling when using Parallel.For](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3240140/11683)

Comment: CPU usage at 100% is a good thing in this case.  You could potentially reduce the priority of your application so it doesn't starve out other operations or make other apps unresponsive.

Comment: In the loop I'm deleting the files

Comment: What storage are the files on?  Seems odd to be 100% CPU here, would expect the storage to be the bottleneck.

Comment: TBH, it could be the code to delete files, but this isn't in the post for us to see. You're already setting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which is correct, so it's something else. Can you try this to limit them, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 1.0))`, in which it should limit that down to around 75%. Do you know how many processors you have?

Comment: Lowering the thread priority will make things a little easier on your CPU, but the processing times will take longer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.priority?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: with a normal foreach loop it is getting timed out so i have chose Parall.Foreach with which my task is completing but the only problem is CPU utilisation is 100%.
Please let me know if we have any alternatives

Comment: @Dortimer `Lowering the thread priority will make things...`, **you can't**. It's a threadpool...

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve here? That your code is timing out indicates that you're doing this as part of a service call of some sort. Probably what you need is a separate service with a queue. Your service passes the file names to be deleted to the queue, and returns. That other service deletes the files in the background.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you can. you just have to set it inside the Parallel.ForEach loop. `Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ...`

Comment: @Dortimer see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089076/1797425

Answer (score -1):

Unlike some ppl in the comments, I understand the point of your question. It's quite reasonable to want control over the amount of CPU a processes uses. Fastest / most CPU possible is not always desirable. For example, you might have a top level thread that needs to servicing requests in a responsive manner. Or you might want to use your computer while this process is running. So a much better option would be to use less than 100% of the CPU.

I run a distributed app at home and, depending on settings, it runs at 100% CPU on unattended PCs and at 50% on PCs that are in use...

So yeah, try MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount / 2

(by default MaxDegreeOfParallelism is set to Environment.ProcessorCount)

Also, and sorry about this, I personally dislike it when ppl start asking why this why that rather than just answering the question........ But when you say your loop times out, what is waiting for the files to be deleted? Can you just queue the delete requests and delete them outside the loop, on another thread/task, at your leisure, without making the caller wait?